# apply function to all instances of an attribute in an object tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming

Let's say I have an object of unknown structure and depth, where I want to modify an attribute. For example, let's imagine that the attribute I want to change is `id` and the structure might be something like this:

```
"{
  "a": "foo",
  "b": "bar",
  "c": {
    "id": {
      "a": "foo"
    },
    "b": "whatever"
  },
  "id": {
    "a": "foo"
  }
}"
```

Is there any stablished pattern or way to take any instance of a wanted key in the whole tree and apply a generic function to it? Ideally, checking array elements too if they existed.

Comment: do you want to change all properties with key `id`? what have you tried?

Comment: **Answerers:** Note the [tag:functional-programming] tag! I missed it and posted an unuseful answer as a result.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I already know how to do it through recursion, but I was wondering if there's a specific pattern to do that in a functional way, to avoid mutating the object as it is traversed - I should have been more clear about that, since I only mentioned functional programming in the question tags. I was reading about lenses but they didn't seem to fit my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of functional programming, we need our structure to be a Functor, that is, supply it with a function `fmap` so that `fmap(fn, someTree)` will yield the same structure with `fn` applied to all values inside it. There are quite a few ways to implement that, for example:

```js
let isObject = x => x && typeof x === 'object';

let map = fn => obj =>
    Array.isArray(obj)
        ? obj.map((v, k) => fn([null, v]).pop())
        : Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(fn));

let _fmap = fn => ([key, val]) =>
    isObject(val)
        ? [
            key,
            map(_fmap(fn))(val)
        ]
        : fn([key, val]);

let fmap = fn => map(_fmap(fn));

//

const renameKey = (o, n) => ([key, val]) => (key === o ? [n, val] : [key, val]);

test = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: [
        {a: 1}, {a: 2}, {b: 3}
    ]
};

newTest = fmap(renameKey('a', 'blah'))(test);

console.log(newTest);
```

Here, we treat a tree "node" as a `[key, value]` pair. The callback receives a pair and is supposed to return it back, with or without a modification.

Comment: That's probably what I was looking for! It *almost* works, with an issue: In case of arrays, it's not returning an array but an object with numeric keys. EDIT: It's also creating some extra  "0":0 properties that it shouldn't, I'm not sure why.

Comment: still not there... it's creating a bunch of arrays with index values and intermediate arrays (sorry about the bother)

Comment: @kace91: no prob... care to make a fiddle with your test data?

Comment: that seems to conserve arrays indeed! The limitation I'm seeing, unless I'm wrong, is that the scope of the function is limited to a given key-value at a time, is that right? That is to say, if I wanted to do something involving more than one attribute at a time it wouldn't work - such as "modify this arrays' atribute A only if the object's attribute B has a certain value"

Comment: @kace91: that's correct, this function only invokes the callback for atomic (non-object) values.